# How to increase the width of the horizontal line using Markdown on GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

I am using the below code for drawing the horizontal line

"-----"

"***"

I want to change the color of the horizontal line plus change the height also.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the [cheatsheet](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet)

Three or more...

Hyphens

`---`

---

Asterisks

`***`

---

Underscores

`___`

---

give you the same thing, which is the standard horizontal line.

You cannot style markdown, you get what you get. Github chooses the style.

Comment: Why is this not always generating a line? It seems to depend on the content before it.

Comment: Yes, you must have a newline before and after

Answer (score 60):

Instead of using *** or ---, try:

```markdown
<hr style="border:2px solid gray">
```

Comment: Strangly the code `<hr style="background-color:blue;"></hr>` does not render blue line in github pages.

Comment: Not working in GitHub Gists ...

Answer (score 37):

You can add a thinner line than the normal one by simply writing an empty heading `#`

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: And you will get into trouble when using some plugin or tool to generate a table of contents from the markdown.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```html
<hr style="border:2px solid blue">
```

Here the colour of the line has been changed as well. This method uses standard HTML markup and works much better than just "***".